# Client to server communication

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been recently looking into something like [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms), and I wondered if you can do the same thing with text to return html coding?

For example;

Index.html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <script>
      function myFunction(html)
      {
        var text = document.getElementsByName("name_1")[0].value;
        document.getElementById("html").innerHTML = html;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="name_1" placeholder="Send url to get text" />
      <input type="button" value="Send url to get text" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myFunction).sendTextToServer()" />
    </form>
    <div id="html"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs:

```
function sendTextToServer() {
  // I don't know how to get the text from index.html
  var text;
  if(text != "") {
    text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(text);
  } else {
    text = 'Unable to fetch html.';
  }

  return text;
}
```

Comment: what issues have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

In that documentation, the `this` keyword is used in the argument section of the function:

```
this.parentNode
```

It would be:

```
onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(myFunction).sendTextToServer(this.parentNode)"
```

in your case.  The button is a child of the form, so the form is a parent of the button.  The code in the button gets the parent of the button, which is the form.  In your code, you left that out.  Which is okay, you just need to get the data some other way if you want to use a different method.

You could first give your input tag an id:

```
<input id='idInputTxt' type="text" name="name_1" placeholder="Send url to get text" />
```

Then get the element by id:

```
function sendTextToServer() {
  //get the text from index.html
  var text = document.getElementById("idInputTxt").value;

  if(text != "") {
    text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(text);
  } else {
    text = 'Unable to fetch html.';
  }

  return text;
}
```

You can also get the entire form object:

Give the form element an id:

```
<form id='idForm1'>
```

Get the form:

```
function sendTextToServer() {
  //get the form data from index.html
  var objForm = document.getElementById("idForm1");
```

If you get the entire form, Apps Script converts it to a smaller object than the form object.  Then you can loop through the values.

Comment: I found it out with your effort, but in code.gs you can't have this line: "document.getElementById("ID")". Document isn't a defined variable / function.

Comment: Right, you need that line in the "script" tag of the HTML, if you wanted to go that route.  It's just an alternative to the `this.parentNode`.